# gradle install "error: package XXXXX does not exist"

Tags: gradle, xsd, xjc

I'm trying to transfer from maven to gradle install for multi projects application and failed with error of missing generated package. Could you help me resolve it?

A sub project has build plugin in POM.xml:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaFiles>**/*.xsd</schemaFiles>
                <packageName>generated</packageName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Java classes are generated from *.xsd schema and store in folder **..\target\generated-sources\jaxb\generated**

run "gradle install" fails with error:

package generated does not exist

import generated.ObjectFactory;

Answer (score 0):

You will need to integrate a JAXB plugin in your Gradle build, to provide an equivalent feature as in the Maven build.

Have a look at the [exising JAXB plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=jaxb) on the Gradle plugin portal.

Comment: I got gradle build error "Plugin with id 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.jaxb2'" after I added "apply plugin: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.jaxb2'" to my build.gradle file in subproject. Could you help more? thanks